# How to save a string as decimal in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "Prices" with one field name "value" and set to decimal.
I want to be able to insert a string such as "3.5$" and that mysql will insert the number "3.5".
No success so far.

Comment: Currency, date formatting, etc belongs in the view. if you pass around simple numbers your life will be a lot easier :)

Comment: Just do a `floatval($theNumber)` before sending to MySQL.

Comment: I'll remove the dollar then. I thought there's a way in mysql. thanks guys.

Comment: is there a better way to cut the dollar sign? im currently using str_replace and feeling dirty

Answer (score 1):

Use [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

```
$NumberWithString = 3.5$;
floatval($NumberWithString);
```

***Example***

```
<?php
    $var = '122.34343The';
    $float_value_of_var = floatval($var);
    echo $float_value_of_var; // 122.34343
?>
```

**EDIT 01**

Or use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$newNumber = preg_replace('/&#36;/', '', $NumberWithString);
```

Comment: @user3800799 Check **EDIT 01**

Comment: @user3800799 happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
update yourtable 
set yourdecimal = cast('3.7$' as decimal(10,2)) 
where id = 1
```

Comment: @user3800799 - This is almost the right answer. Since in your comments you state " I thought there's a way in mysql.". I believe the OP is wanting to insert however